# Assigning a Random Number to a Row Between 1 and N in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to work out the best way to assign a number randomly between 1 and N to a row such that each row is distinct. (N being the number of rows in the dataset). The number of rows could be 10M plus, so this might not be the approach).

Initial thoughts were to generate an array using a udf but i'm unsure how to go about assigning each index of the array to a row.

```html
def create_rand_range(end):
    return list(random.sample(range(1, end), end-1))
```

Example:
n = 3
create_rand_range = [3,1,2]

datatable output:

```html
| Col 1 | Rand_Output |
|-------|-------------|
| A     | 3           |
| B     | 1           |
| C     | 2           |
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Here are couple of examples to assign number to rows.

#### Option#1: Use [monotonically_increasing_id()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.monotonically_increasing_id) function.

```
##sample dataframe    
df = spark.createDataFrame([('A',),('B',),('C',),('D',) ],["dummy"])

##monotonically_increasing_id function
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
df.withColumn("Rand_Output ",psf.monotonically_increasing_id()).show()


#+-----+------------+
#|dummy|Rand_Output |
#+-----+------------+
#|    A|  8589934592|
#|    B| 25769803776|
#|    C| 42949672960|
#|    D| 60129542144|
#+-----+------------+
```

#### Option#2: Use [Window](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/window.html#Window) functions

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
from pyspark.sql import window as psw

w = psw.Window().partitionBy(psf.lit('a')).orderBy(psf.lit('a'))
df.withColumn("row_num", psf.row_number().over(w)).show()

#+-----+-------+
#|dummy|row_num|
#+-----+-------+
#|    A|      1|
#|    B|      2|
#|    C|      3|
#|    D|      4|
#+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Hi, so i don't think this would work as it would not be random. For context rows 1 --> 10 for example are duplicates and i want to assign a random id to each of them (not a monotonically increasing one). This would then allow me to join it randomly onto another dataset.

Comment: I have updated my answer to solve this scenario and added option#2 using windowing functions.

Answer (score 1):

The ran() function from pyspark.sql.functions generates a uniform random output between 0 and 1. In order to transform that distribution into a Uniform discrete distribution over the set {1,2,...,N} it suffices to multiply the random uniform output by N and afterwards taking floor function.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
N=df.count()
df.withColumn("random_number_N", F.floor(F.lit(N)*F.rand()))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by udf in this way:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

num_list = np.arange(1, df.count()+1, 1).tolist()

def delete_rand_items():
    global num_list
    to_delete = random.sample(range(len(num_list)),1)
    x = num_list[to_delete[0]]
    num_list = [x for i,x in enumerate(num_list) if not i in to_delete]
    return x
```

and then define new column with this udf:

```
assign_num = F.udf(delete_rand_items, IntegerType())
df = df.withColumn('Rand_output', assign_num())
```